# Database and listview error

Tags: android, database, listview

i got a problem with custom list view. i got this error 
"                                                     at com.example.azat_pc.nekadarkaldi.EventsActivity$myAdapter.getView(EventsActivity.java:78)
"
here is my project;
https://github.com/azatgoktas/nekadarkaldi
so whats wrong with this thing?

Comment: Please be specific on exact error you're getting. If.you can post the error

Comment: Add your code here so it's easier to look at rather people navigate back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the following changes: 
[Click here Download the project-after-changes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xasr445mmxm5xrv/nekadarkaldi-master.zip?dl=0)

In the **EventsActivity** class

Change

```
 public myAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Events> objects, Activity activity) {
```

to

```
  public myAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<Events> objects) {
```

and change

```
year= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year);
```

to

```
 year= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.year);
```

Other changes can be seen in the project..

Comment: Thank you:). I solved the problem. But why should i do like
 year= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.year);this

Comment: You are welcome, because the context of (convertView) is differ from the current context of the application, and current context cannot access the controls in another context..

Comment: Alright,i got you:) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the following

```
convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(resource,null);
```

To

```
convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId, parent, false);
```

Comment: I got same error again.